# Managing TPS in a distributed Java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openshift, hazelcast

I have a distributed Java spring-boot application in Openshift.
The application is deployed on N clusters with N number of pods. The application works with a Postgres database.
The application must get records from the table from this database and send them to another application.
How can you regulate the total final TPS from all clusters from all pod's?

I think, I can use hazelcast to adjust TPS from one cluster, but I can’t figure out how to adjust it within N clusters
Or implement some mechanism at the table level...

I don’t want to implement a bicycle, what solutions are currently available for such a problem? best practice?